# Is it possible to inspect the command line arguments passed to an VB6 app from outside the app

Tags: security, vb6, command-line-arguments, piracy-prevention, piracy-protection

I have a VB6 application that has a licensing module in VB6 which checks for the authenticated user. If authentication is successful, this application calls main application with authentication information. Now, I wanted to pass information in encrypted format from licensing application to main application through command line parameters. The main application will read command line arguments and checks whether user is authenticated or not. The authentication in main application is required as user can directly open the main application and use it without license.

I am concerned about the level of security with this approach. In web application, we can use various tools like fiddler to examine and view the request/response made by web application. **Is there a tool through which user can examine or view Command line arguments passed to/from VB6 application?**

Comment: Interesting question but not directly related to VB6

Comment: The command line of a running process is visible to any application. This is then visible to the user in both Task Manager and Process Explorer.

Comment: Task Manager only shows that info on Vista and upwards, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, In VB6 you can use `Command$` to view command line arguments, and similarly almost all programming languages and technologies would have such command/tool to view command line arguments. One could replace your exe with his/her own exe and just print(like MessageBox) command line arguments.

Now, either change the title of your question or post new question to get some suggestions regarding security model. It would be better to first google the risks regarding this model and other good models

**Edit**

If you mean "outside the application" then i think replacing the exe would work provided one has such access i.e. s/he can replace the exe of your application by his/her own which would just dump the arguments.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked. He want to know if you can inspect the command line arguments passed to an application from outside the app.

Comment: @MattWilko Though i could not see such hint which says "Outside the app", otherwise you are right.

Comment: Yes, I mean "Outside the app". Updated title of question. Thanks @Matt Wilko

Comment: @bjan Good catch of replacing exe and printing command line args. I was not able to think of this simple hack.

Answer (score 6):

One example of a tool that can see this is [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). The command-line arguments will show in the Detail column along with the full path to the exe.
Starting with [Windows Vista](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager#Windows_Vista_changes), these values can also be shown in Task Manager.